# Compare one base value against all other values of two columns within groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Say I have this tibble:

```
d <- tibble::tribble(
        ~food,    ~country,      ~mean,        ~lb,        ~ub,
      "Apple",    "Belize", 39.9776055, 29.0792484,  55.206794,
  "Fettucine",    "Belize", 61.0975745, 51.5185944, 71.5280344,
     "Gateau",    "Belize", 49.5463782,  30.639024, 48.8724726,
  "Ice_cream",    "Belize", 29.8140732, 32.1812985,  57.351144,
    "Lentils",    "Belize", 48.9155095, 25.3083386, 43.3615929,
     "Sorbet",    "Belize", 41.3195049, 22.0809335,   46.27327,
     "Tomato",    "Belize",  36.578878, 28.5499326, 52.5901827,
  "Tangerine",    "Belize", 47.6379792,  20.171187, 42.8531992,
      "Apple", "Nicaragua", 46.5045615, 34.7335467,  51.910866,
  "Fettucine", "Nicaragua",  49.154144, 25.9897836, 50.9296656,
     "Gateau", "Nicaragua",  42.712395,  24.681436, 54.0169434,
  "Ice_cream", "Nicaragua", 50.5182907, 33.8316215,  46.545856,
    "Lentils", "Nicaragua", 31.6069446, 23.0752499, 43.3615929,
     "Sorbet", "Nicaragua", 48.3360246,  19.796699,   49.46453,
     "Tomato", "Nicaragua",  44.361618, 22.3769742, 47.8806141,
  "Tangerine", "Nicaragua", 31.0024944,  31.377402, 57.3926775
  )
```

I want to generate a new column `stat_sig` that checks within each value of `country` whether the `mean` value of `Fettucine` is greater than the `ub` value of the other foods and lower than the value of `lb` of the other foods. For example, the code below performs the test for food==Apple vs. food==Fettucine within country:

```r
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
    group_by(country) %>% 
    mutate(stat_sig = case_when(
        mean[food=="Fettucine"] > ub[food=="Apple"] ~ "positive",
        mean[food=="Fettucine"] < lb[food=="Apple"] ~ "negative", 
        TRUE ~ "no difference")
    )
```

But my various attempts to abstract this so i can perform the test for each value of `food!="Fettucine"` against `food=="Fettucine"` have failed. Can anyone offer any insights to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are comparing one value (`mean[food=="Fettucine"]`) to all other values in specific columns, you don't need to do indexing for other columns, just the column name is enough.

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(stat_sig = case_when(
    mean[food=="Fettucine"] > ub ~ "positive",
    mean[food=="Fettucine"] < lb ~ "negative", 
    TRUE ~ "no difference")
  )

# A tibble: 16 × 6
# Groups:   country [2]
   food      country    mean    lb    ub stat_sig     
   <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        
 1 Apple     Belize     40.0  29.1  55.2 positive     
 2 Fettucine Belize     61.1  51.5  71.5 no difference
 3 Gateau    Belize     49.5  30.6  48.9 positive     
 4 Ice_cream Belize     29.8  32.2  57.4 positive     
 5 Lentils   Belize     48.9  25.3  43.4 positive     
 6 Sorbet    Belize     41.3  22.1  46.3 positive     
 7 Tomato    Belize     36.6  28.5  52.6 positive     
 8 Tangerine Belize     47.6  20.2  42.9 positive     
 9 Apple     Nicaragua  46.5  34.7  51.9 no difference
10 Fettucine Nicaragua  49.2  26.0  50.9 no difference
11 Gateau    Nicaragua  42.7  24.7  54.0 no difference
12 Ice_cream Nicaragua  50.5  33.8  46.5 positive     
13 Lentils   Nicaragua  31.6  23.1  43.4 positive     
14 Sorbet    Nicaragua  48.3  19.8  49.5 no difference
15 Tomato    Nicaragua  44.4  22.4  47.9 positive     
16 Tangerine Nicaragua  31.0  31.4  57.4 no difference
```